Error: Access is Denied during PostgreSQL Installation on Windows 11
I'm encountering an issue while trying to install PostgreSQL on my Windows 11 machine. During the installation process, I received an error message stating "Access is denied." Below is a screenshot of the error:
There has been an error.
Error running C:\WINDOWS\System32\icacls "C:\Users\tanma\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_a369da0643" /T /Q /grant "tanmay:(OI)(CI)F": C:\Users\tanma\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_a369da0643\*: Access is denied.

I've tried the following solutions but the issue persists:
Running the installer as an administrator.
Checking the permissions of the Temp directory.
Disabling my antivirus software.


I'll vote to close this, like the many other identical questions. You have to pester EnterpriseDB to fix the bug in their installer. Ideally, reply to the thread on the pgsql-hackers mailing list and describe your exact environment.

Hi @tanmay, I am also facing same issue. Did you get any solution till now?

Here are my steps:  reinstalled Windows 11 to reset system files and user account configurations, set up user accounts with full administrative privileges, and reinstalled PostgreSQL without encountering the "Access is denied" error.

I also encountered the same issue. What i did was log out of my microsoft account  and log in as local account in my computer. Make sure to log in as admin. Try installing it again

Thanks, I guess it is also an admin rights issue. I reinstalled Windows. it works for me

Same issue. I was able to get around this by navigating directly to the specific temp folder the installer created and getting access to it WHILE the installer error is showing.

This way you can hit 'retry' after the change and the installation will continue.

